# Python beautifulsoup grab table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to grab the table out of this webpage. I'm not sure if I'm grabbing the right tags. Here is what I have so far.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page='http://www.airchina.com.cn/www/en/html/index/ir/traffic/'

r=requests.get(page)

soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text)

test=soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'main noneBg'})
rows=test.findAll("td")
```

Is `main noneBg` the table? when i hover over that tag, it does highlight the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you need is in the `iframe` that is loaded from a different URL.

Here's how you can grab it (watch the URL is different):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = 'http://www.airchina.com.cn/www/jsp/airlines_operating_data/exlshow_en.jsp'

r = requests.get(page)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

div = soup.find('div', class_='mainRight').find_all('div')[1]
table = div.find('table', recursive=False)
for row in table.find_all('tr', recursive=False):
    for cell in row('td', recursive=False):
        print cell.text.strip()
```

prints:

```
Feb 2014
% change vs Feb 2013
% change vs Jan 2014
Cumulative Feb 2014
% cumulative change
1.Traffic
1.RTKs (in millions)
1407.8
...
```

Note that you need to use `recursive=False` due to the nested tables on the page.

Comment: `print cell.text
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3: illegal multibyte sequence` getting this error on the last line.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm a beginner. What would the code look like? `cell.text.decode('utf-8').split()` ?

Comment: `return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)` looks like similar issue

Comment: ha. ok. that will take me a while to figure out. i'll accept your answer first.

Comment: why does your code work for you but not for me? different version of python?

Comment: Bravo!!! worked. your last comment fixed it. Thank you! But why does the code work for you without that line? i'm curious to know. I'm running python 2.7.